# How does installers check for java version

Tags: java, windows, installation

What method(s) is usually used by program installer to check java version? Do they use simple "java -version" command or is there some other more sophisticated ways.
*Windows OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way *I'd* check for the Java version is running a simple class with the following:

```
class VersionChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }
}
```

EDIT: The reason why is that `java -version` will give something like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

and I don't want to have to parse that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I mean if the installer checks for java before installation. Would the installer be able to execute java code you mentioned ?

Comment: It sure could, `java VersionChecker.class` from the installer program